# Apache Flink + CEP - Detect same events

Tags: java, scala, stream, apache-flink, complex-event-processing

I'd like to detect events that share the same property. Suppose I have a simple case class:

```
case class Record(name: String, value: Int)
```

Suppose there is the following stream:

```
Record("A", 1)
Record("B", 2)
Record("A", 3)
Record("C", 4)
```

Then I'd like to detect the double "A" record. Is this possible? I now have this:

```
val start: Pattern[Record, _] = myStream
.begin("first")
.followedBy("second").where(previous_record.name == _.name)
```

Comment: To detect on same property you need large store space as the property set can be infinite, 
for each property seen you need to store. If the property set is limited than you can apply filtering.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are defining  what is Event detection, have you tried this:

```
val start: Pattern[Record, _] = myStream
   .begin("first").where(name == "A")
   .followedBy("second").where(name == "A")
```

**Update**: For example:

```
val patternIG: Pattern[(String,String), _] = Pattern.begin[String,String)]("start").where(_.name == "Ignition").where(_.ac == "ON").next("end").where(_.name == "Door").where(_.ac == "ON")
val patternStream: PatternStream[(String,String)] = CEP.pattern(mystream, patternIG)
def selectFn(pattern : mutable.Map[String,(String,String)]): String = {
val startEvent = pattern.get("start").get
val endEvent = pattern.get("end").get
  "ALERT Door Open"
}
val patternStreamSelected = patternStream.select(selectFn(_)).print()
```

Comment: Almost. Problem here is that the "A" is defined in the previous record, so it is variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a keyBy(name) operation before CEP.